# What are the all conditions to be tangent to x-axis for a polynomial?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials

For a polynomial function $f$, what are all conditions to be tangent to the $x$-axis. For $a \in \mathbb{R}$ I know that $f(a)=0,$ $f'(a)=0$ should be satisfied. But I encountered a polynomial:
$$
x\mapsto x^5+x^3.
$$
Conditions I wrote is already satisfied with it for $a=0$. But apparently, it is not tangent to the $x$-axis.

[image]

Seems like the problem here is $f''$ changes sign at $x=0$. Are there other things that I should also check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the graph of the polynomial will be tangent to the $x$-axis if it has a multiple root.  A couple of issues with what you wrote:

1. You insist that $f(0) = 0$, but this is more than just "tangent to the $x$-axis,"  it's actually "tangent to the $x$-axis at the origin."  Is that what you wanted?  If so, then the answer is "the polynomial is divisible by $x^2$."
2. The graph of $y=x^5+x^3$ is, in fact, tangent to the $x$-axis (at $x=0$) so I don't understand why you say it's not.  Did you mean that it should not cross the $x$-axis?  If so, the answer is "the polynomial is exactly divisible by an even power of $x$ (if $f(0)=0$ is required) or $x-a$ (if not.)

Comment: Yes, i want that it doesn't across the $x$-axis, how can i tell it mathematically?

Comment: It's what I said in 2.  You need an even power of the factor.

Answer (score 0):

Your polynomial function $x\mapsto x^5+x^3$ is in fact **tangent** to the $x$-axis.

Your conditions are correct.

Your error is the following: a function **can** cross its tangent (it is indeed the case if $f''$ switch signs).

Another example would be $x\mapsto x^3$ at $x=0$:

[image]